# Cocoa: prevent window from leaving the screen

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm (re-)writing a small app to control a USB device. I would like the window of that app to be always entirely visible. So when you move around the window, it stops moving when the bottom hits the bottom of the screen or one of the sides hits the side of the screen.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.
Normal NSWindows with a title bar constrain their own frames to not allow the top of the window to leave the top of the screen. This is done in `-[NSWindow constrainFrameRect:toScreen:]`
You can override this method to constrain the frame however you'd like.

Comment: Had a look at this method, not sure I understand it completely but I'll give it a go. Of course a ready to implement solution is always welcome... ;-) Tanks, Arjen

Comment: You asked it was possible. The answer is yes. Google for that method; I'm sure you'll find people using it for the same purpose.

Comment: True, and I'm working on that. But that does not mean a ready made solution isn't welcome...

Comment: OK, so I tried overruling constrainFramerectToScreen, but I must do something wrong. Even When I try to set origin to (0,0) I can still move the window freely around.. And Google did not point me to an example I could understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the user from being able to freely move the window, simply make a custom window with no title bar. Having a title bar indicates to the user that the window can be moved, so the solution here is to not have one. Then, there's no control for moving it. You'll need to provide your own controls for closing the window.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want. I just want the window to not be able to be moved off screen. It's for an app controlling stuff in my holiday cottage, running on a local Mac. When en route I access this application via my iPhone through VNC. This is difficult enough with the slow respons I get on cellular, but when somebody moves the app off screen it's almost impossible to get it back. Since I made the window floating so it's easy to find, I also need to be able to move it around in order to see other applications running.

Comment: Then the method I mentioned in the other answer is what you need. Just make an NSWindow subclass and implement this method.  Make sure you make your window be that subclass in Interface Builder.

Comment: As far as I understand that's what I did. I named the window appWindow in IB and tried all kinds of things with my attempt to override frameRectToScreen (including pinning the origin at 0,0) but none of that did anything. The window was still free to be moved anywhere...

Comment: Somehow the automatic restore function in (Mountain)Lion overrules all positioning settings. When I put "[appWindow setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(0,0)]; in awakeFromNib (as the last line in that function) it keeps positioning the window in the position it was when I last closed the application, ignoring my setFrameOrigin. This is exactly what happens when I try to override frameRectToScreen...

Comment: Well, I managed to override the standard Lion restore settings (NSUserDefaults) so now my window starts where I put it in awakeFromNib. Overriding frameRectToScreen still does nothing...

Comment: When I put `code` - (NSRect)constrainFrameRect:(NSRect)frameRect toScreen:(NSScreen *)screen
{
    return frameRect;
}
between @implementation and @end in my window definition, I understand I override the method and the window should be able to move over the menu bar and below the dock. But this does not happen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here's a simple example showing constrainFrameRect:toScreen: https://www.dropbox.com/s/24xq65brgedbels/TestWindow.zip

Comment: Comment from Yesterday seems to be gone, so once again thanks for taking the time to make this example. When I open your project and run it, it does exactly what it should. The window jumps back to the lower left corner. However, when I paste the code into my project nothing happens. When I create a new project and copy your code there and connect the right things in IB I get the window to stay put in the corner again. I won't give up, but I will be busy with other things in the next few weeks so thanks again and I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: Found it... In IB mainWindow was still set to NSWindow in stead of my subclass. So I was not overriding anything. Thanks again,  Arjen

Answer (score 0):

With the code example provided by [Ken Aspeslagh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205032/ken-aspeslagh) no longer available via the Dropbox link, I thought it would be useful to share my solution. For my project, I only needed to worry about the bottom and right side of the screen, but others should be able to adapt this to account for the top and left side of the screen.

```
- (NSRect)constrainFrameRect:(NSRect)frameRect toScreen:(NSScreen *)screen
{
    if (((self.frame.origin.x + self.frame.size.width) > screen.frame.size.width) && (screen.frame.size.width > 0))
    {
        frameRect.origin.x = (screen.frame.size.width - self.frame.size.width);
    }

    if (self.frame.origin.y < 0)
    {
        frameRect.origin.y = 0;
    }

    return frameRect;
}
```